# Looping through HTML & following links

Tags: python, html, loops, for-loop, beautifulsoup

I am writing a code that is supposed to open a url, identify the 3rd link and repeat this process 3 times (each time with the new url).

I wrote a loop (below), but it seems to each time sart over with the original url.

Can someone help me fix my code?

```
import urllib.request, urllib.parse, urllib.error
from urllib.parse import urljoin
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

#blanc list
l = []

#starting url
url = input('Enter URL: ')
if len(url) < 1:
    url = 'http://py4e-data.dr-chuck.net/known_by_Fikret.html'

#loop 
for _ in range(4):
    html = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()    #open url
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')    #parse through BeautifulSoup
    tags = soup('a')    #extract tags
    
    for tag in tags:
        url = tag.get('href', None)    #extract links from tags
        l.append(url)    #add the links to a list
        url = l[2:3]    #slice the list to extract the 3rd url
        url = ' '.join(str(e) for e in url)    #change the type to string
    print(url)

Current Output: 
http://py4e-data.dr-chuck.net/known_by_Montgomery.html
http://py4e-data.dr-chuck.net/known_by_Montgomery.html
http://py4e-data.dr-chuck.net/known_by_Montgomery.html
http://py4e-data.dr-chuck.net/known_by_Montgomery.html

Desired output:
http://py4e-data.dr-chuck.net/known_by_Montgomery.html
http://py4e-data.dr-chuck.net/known_by_Mhairade.html
http://py4e-data.dr-chuck.net/known_by_Butchi.html
http://py4e-data.dr-chuck.net/known_by_Anayah.html
```

Comment: is this school assignment?

Comment: Yes, it is for a class I'm taking :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define the empty list within the loop. The following code works:

```
import urllib.request, urllib.parse, urllib.error
from urllib.parse import urljoin
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

#blanc list
# l = []

#starting url
url = input('Enter URL: ')
if len(url) < 1:
    url = 'http://py4e-data.dr-chuck.net/known_by_Fikret.html'

#loop 
for _ in range(4):
    l = []
    html = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()    #open url
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')    #parse through BeautifulSoup
    tags = soup('a')    #extract tags
    
    for tag in tags:
        url = tag.get('href', None)    #extract links from tags
        l.append(url)    #add the links to a list
        url = l[2:3]    #slice the list to extract the 3rd url
        url = ' '.join(str(e) for e in url)    #change the type to string
    print(url)
```

Result in terminal:

```
http://py4e-data.dr-chuck.net/known_by_Montgomery.html
http://py4e-data.dr-chuck.net/known_by_Mhairade.html
http://py4e-data.dr-chuck.net/known_by_Butchi.html
http://py4e-data.dr-chuck.net/known_by_Anayah.html
```

Answer (score 0):

Just making it simple for You in your way with 1 loop:

```py
for _ in range(4):
    html = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()    #open url
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')    #parse through BeautifulSoup
    tag = soup('a')[2]
    url = tag.get('href', None)
    print(url)
```